# Best practice for Testing with Python in VSC

Tags: python, testing, visual-studio-code

I would like to ask for your recommendation about coding in Python, mainly with VSC. I have read several Python standards but I have several doubts about testing. I have found some good extensions in VSC marketplace and (to me) the more relevant are installed with Python Official Extension.

I have little experience with testing and I have only used unittest, but reading [here](https://realpython.com/python-testing/) I believe Pytest is far more complete, should I change to it?

A "basic" test extension is installed with Python Official Extension from VSC, but I don't know if there are better extensions for this. I suppose it is compatible with unittest, pytest and nose. What I don't is how to do test in several Python version with VSC, I believe is a good practice, but I don't know if I must have installed all the other Python versions to do this.

Comment: Hi Alex, it's being closed because subjective questions asking for suggestions on what tool is 'best' are off-topic for Stackoverflow's format, you need a long-format answer and that doesn't fit with the Q&A model.  It's probably best to ask on a forum or search for relevant articles or tutorials online.  e.g. the first result on google for  `python visual studio code testing`  is: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/testing

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment. I will search for another plaform then to this question. BTW, I already read that link, but still have a doubts, therefore, this post. Really, thank you

Answer (score -1):

> I have find some good extensions in VSC marketplace and (to me) the more relevant are installed with Python Official Extension

Yes this is correct. Most packages needed for basic python programming are included in the official extension. Ofcourse there are some great packages out there that aren't included but still can be quite usefull.

> I have little experience with test and I have only use the unittest, but reading here I believe Pytest is far more complete, should I change to it?

Pytest is very easy to use and definatly a recommender, I use it myself and never thaught of changing.

> What I don't is how to do test in several Python version with VSC

I recommend [tox](https://pypi.org/project/tox/), their readme even has an example of exactly what you want to do, testing (with pytest) on multiple python versions.

Hope this clears things up.

Comment: Thanks, I just used tox, but because I don't have installed python37 or 36 it does not run the test there. I will search how to do it, probably a virtual environment with each python version but 'same' dependencies for it to work.

Comment: @AlexTurner see [link](https://tox.wiki/en/latest/#:~:text=environment%20%2D%20for%20each,with%20%2Dr/%2D%2Drecreate.), tox will automatically search for an interpreter with the matching version and create it's own virtual environment, you just need to have the different python versions installed.